# Elasticsearch query for geo_point structure

Tags: elasticsearch

some of my documents have a field geo_point with a structure:

```
{
  "geoLocation" :  [
     45.32,
     33.33
    ]
}
```

and some of them with a structure:

```
{
   "geoLocation" : {
         "lat" : 22.22,
         "lon" : 66.66
   }
}
```

Is there a way to find all the results with the first structure mentioned? I would like to unify the "geoLocation" field.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not sure if I understand the question. I dont have a problem writing geo querry (i.e. Geo-distance). All I want is to have to have a similar structure for all the geoLocation fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unify the `geoLocation` field, what you can do is to run an update by query on all documents and only update a subset of them. The following will update all `geoLocation` arrays to the `lat/lon` object version.

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
    if (ctx._source.geoLocation instanceof ArrayList) {
      ctx._source.geoLocation = [
        "lat": ctx._source.geoLocation[1],
        "lon": ctx._source.geoLocation[0]
      ];
    }
    """
  }
}
```

If you want to make the update the other way around (object to array), you can do it like this:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
    if (ctx._source.geoLocation instanceof Map) {
      ctx._source.geoLocation = [ ctx._source.geoLocation.lon, ctx._source.geoLocation.lat ];
    }
    """
  }
}
```